# Creating an elementwise replacement rule

Tags: replacement, rule

I apologise for the simple question, but I've trying to learn to write my code in a more idiomatic way, after having learned Mathematica mostly through trial and error for a long time.

Say I have two lists

```
l1={x,y,z}
l2={a,b,c}
```

And I want to create a replacement rule

```
{x->a,y->b,z->c}
```

I can achieve this through

```
Table[l1[[i]] -> l2[[i]], {i, 1, Length[l1]}]
```

But this feels cumbersome and I was wondering if there's a cleaner, more idiomatic way of making the same replacement rule?

Comment: Take a look at `Thread` / `AssociationThread`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Thread[ l1 -> l2]
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, in Mathematica, there are several ways to do it.

```
Rule@@@Transpose@{l1, l2}
```

is one way although

```
Thread@Rule[l1, l2]
```

is probably more direct.